# PayPal in-app purchase breaks the Terms Conditions?

Tags: android, paypal

Does using PayPal for in app purchase, like more stars for a game, break the Terms and conditions for the Play Store?

Lets say that I developed a racing game and I want to include an option to buy new cars and tracks, can I use the PayPal in-app purchase system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does.

From the [policy](http://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html):

> In-app purchases:
>
> Developers offering virtual goods or currencies within a game downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment.